# Method to visually show differences between two files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, diff

I'm currently working on a project where I need to "diff" two files.  The major stumbling block I've run into is how to get an overall "map" to see where the differences are between the two projects.  Many programs have a window which has different colors on it to show where the two files are different.  I have tried to create such a thing by painting lines on a panel to represent the differences but it noticeably jitters when the control is repainting, even if there are only 100 lines on it.  Is there a way to make it so that I dont have to repaint all the lines each time and have it repaint automatically (bonus points for stretching when the control is resized)?

Comment: Did you try setting [DoubleBuffer](http://www.bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.htm) on the form?

Comment: Ugh...I'm an idiot.  I should have thought of DoubleBuffering.  Indeed, doublebuffering the panel does the trick although you have to create a new component that inherits from "Panel" and set DoubleBufferred = true.  When I finish the code for my compare mapper, I will post it as an answer so others can use it if nobody else answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an extension such as [CodeCompare](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b)?